# Using rxjs, how to map each element to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I suspect this isn't hard, but I can't figure out how to do it. I have an array of objects, and each object contains an array. After doing some additional processing, I want to retrieve a remote resource for each of the elements. My problem is that my function returns an array, but I want the elements of the array separate.

```
return Rx.Observable.from([                                // 1
    { "rosters": ["a/name1", "b/name2"] },
    { "rosters": ["c/name3", "c/name4"] }])
  .map(group => group.rosters)                             // 2
  .map(roster => roster.substring(0, roster.indexOf('/'))) // 3
  .distinct() // have I seen this before?
  .map(folder => http.get(URL + folder + '/ads.json').map(res => res.json())
  .map(adData => adData.ads)
  .reduce(/* choose random ad */);
```

I want the function at #2 to return data such that each enter of #3 is a separate string. Right now coming into #3 are arrays (in my example pairs of strings). Thanks!

Comment: First of all, do you need square brackets around your objects? i.e. In your first line, you currently have `.from( { "rosters": ... }, {...} )`. Should that be `.from( [ { "rosters": ...}, {...} ] )`? Note the insertion of the square brackets. I get an error when I don't have them.

Comment: You're right, that was a typo in my question, but not in the code. Thank you, changed to what you suggested

Comment: I am not familiar with Rx in particular, but I wonder if `flatMap` might serve the purpose at (2)

Comment: Right now the function at #2 returns two arrays of two items each. Do you, instead, want four items returned (i.e. "a...", "b...", "c...", "c...") or just two items returned, e.g. the first of each array (i.e. "a...", "c...")?

Comment: @AndrewWillems I want the former "a...", "b...", "c...", "c..."

Comment: It's looking like `flatMap` that @tmslnz suggested seems to be working! If someone wants to create an answer I'll happily accept, thanks!!

Comment: I got the 4 items emitted separately using flatMap, but I must admit I'm not exactly sure why. I just inserted `.flatMap(x => x)`. Is that what you did, @ShawnLauzon?

Comment: I simply changed line 2 from map to flatMap. My code isn't completely working yet, but it seems to be past the current problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With assistance both from the OP as well as from @tmslnz...

Change `.map(group => group.roster)` to `.flatMap(group => group.roster)`.